# Embedding python in C in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, makefile, runtime-error, python-embedding

I have the following directory structure:

```
Python-3.4.5
    Lib
    Include
numpy-master
    numpy
scipy-master
    scipy
scikit-learn
    sklearn
pythoncode.py
pythoncode.c
```

`pythoncode.c` contains:-

```
#include <Python.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* file;

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    file = fopen("pythoncode.py","r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "pythoncode.py");
    Py_Finalize();

    return;
}
```

`pythoncode.py` contains:-

```
import sklearn, numpy, scipy
```

I want to run `pythoncode.py` through `pythoncode.c` using `Python-3.4.5` on Windows. I tried using these lines:-

```
gcc -I Python-3.4.5\Include -I Python-3.4.5\PC -c pythoncode.c -w
gcc -shared pythoncode.o -L  Python-3.4.5\Lib -w
```

Compilation (1st line) works, but 2nd line gives following error:-

```
pythoncode.o:pythoncode.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramName'
pythoncode.o:pythoncode.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
pythoncode.o:pythoncode.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_imp__PySys_SetArgv'
pythoncode.o:pythoncode.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags'
pythoncode.o:pythoncode.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried `gcc -shared TerrainPredict.o -L  Python-3.4.5\Lib -w -lpython34` which gives another error:-

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython34
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong here? What is the correct way to run the program as I described. (The directories are source directories directly downloaded from web)

**EDIT**:-

Now I am able to compile and link the `pythoncode.c` file, but on running the executable I get the following:-

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f48fdd6d440 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, my new makefile is:-

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-I Python-3.4.5/Include -I Python-3.4.5 -c -w
LLFLAGS=-o TerrainPredict Python-3.4.5/libpython3.4m.a -lm -lpthread -lutil -ldl

all:
    # set PYTHONHOME=Python-3.4.5
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) TerrainPredict.c
    $(CC) TerrainPredict.o $(LLFLAGS)
```

I built python on ubuntu and created the `libpython3.4m.a` file.
I tried setting `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` variables, but that did not help.

What I am doing wrong now?

Comment: In the `Python-3.4.5\Lib` directory, is there a file named `libpython34.a` or `python34.lib` or similar?

Comment: Also, don't use the `-shared` flag when linking, that's for creating shared libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No. But there is libpython34.py

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That did not change anything

Comment: Are you sure that it's `libpython34.py`, with the `.py` ending? That's not a linker library, it seems that your installation is incomplete.

Comment: Do I need to build python 3.4? If yes, how? (I tried building but that had other errors)

Comment: Yes `libpython34.py` contains python code

Comment: I do not want to install python on system PATH (Other functions should not be disturbed)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do you have any idea about how to get a `linpython34.a`?

Comment: any updates in this thread?

Answer (score 2):

I am using VSCode in windows with these arguments to GCC calls while building the c source.

```
gcc<space>-g<space>-o<space>"project_folder"<space>-IC:/Python37/include/<space>-LC:/Python37/libs/<space>'path/to/your/source.c'<space>-lpython37
```